# What data is sent to Apple when using an Apple Maps view on my iOS application?

Tags: ios, maps, apple-maps

My company is weighing the pros and cons of using an Apple Maps implementation for a map view in our iOS app. We're trying to determine what data is sent to Apple when we use Apple Maps within our application. We have privacy concerns for our customer's data, and so knowing what data is shared to Apple and whether it is sent in an encrypted fashion is important to us.

I'm not really sure where to start looking to determine this. Is anyone familiar with the subject area and able to point me in the right direction in where to start looking?

Comment: Information is available here - https://www.apple.com/au/privacy/ Essentially Apple would receive the IP address of the device (since it needs to send the map data back) and the region of the map that is requested.  Apple doesn't receive any personally identifying information nor the specific location of the device/user

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your answer. Do you know about privacy for the application itself? How can I determine if Apple is storing application identifiers with map usage. That would allow Apple to make inferences about what our customers as a whole are doing with our application. For example if the application id for Uber was tracked with usage then Apple would be able to determine how Uber's customers were using Uber.

Comment: All I can say is that behaviour is the least Apple-like behaviour I can imagine.  They simply don't do those sort of things.